# How do I select rows where I x% of the columns have NaN values in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df with floats and NaNs.
How do I select rows where >1000 columns have Nan?

I have tried

```
df[(df == NaN).sum(axis=1)>1000])
```

but get:

```
NameError: name 'NaN' is not defined
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try

```
 df[(df.isna()).sum(axis=1)>1000]
```